# django | model.objects.filter(user = request.user) not returning any data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I've been trying to render out user specific content, but when I use the line 'Job.objects.filter(user = request.user)' I don't get anything rendered in the form. I don't think that the problem is the template because when I use the line Job.objects.all() all instances are rendered out with no problem. What I'm trying to do is render out the instances that are 'posted' by a user.

EDIT:

I nearly have a solution for this but I have one more problem to solve. I have a new line in views.py and it is filtering the Job objects by checking if the contact_email is equal to request.user.email. This technically works but it brings forth another problem. User's can use any email they want in the form, not just the email they logged in with. My solution to this is to remove the contact_email field from the form so no user can edit the contact_email value. Then in models.py I need to make the default value of contact_email equal to request.user.email or Account.email.

Setting this default is where I'm stuck at. I've attempted this method many times unsuccessfully, so I would really appreciate some suggestions on how I can set this default value.

Thanks

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def manage_jobs(request):
    if request.user.is_employee:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = JobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        jobs = Job.objects.filter(contact_email=request.user.email) #updated
        context = {"form":form, "jobs":jobs}
        return render(request, 'employer/manage-jobs.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Are you using FilmLink as an employee?')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'is_employee']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ("post_jobs", "Can post jobs"),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_perms(self, perm):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

class Job(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, verbose_name="Company/Employer")
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    area_of_filming = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Area Of Filming", default="")
    contact_email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Contact Email', max_length=60, default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, default='', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company
```

manage-jobs.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>FilmLink</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'lng/css/manage-jobs.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'lng/css/manage-jobs-nav.css' %}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <button id="myBtn">Post A Job</button>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times</span>
        <form action="{% url 'manage-jobs' %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div id="company-container">
            <p>Employer Name</p>
            <p id="employer">{{form.company}}</p>
          </div>
          <div id="role-container">
            <p>Role (e.g. Actor, Director)</p>
            <p id="role">{{form.role}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="area-of-filming-container">
            <p>Area Of Production/Filming</p>
            <p id="area-of-filming">{{form.area_of_filming}}</p>
          </div>
          <div id="description-container">
            <p>Description Of Job</p>
            <p id="description">{{form.description}}</p>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id="post-job">Publish Job</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h1>
      {% for job in jobs %} {{job.company}} {{job.description}} {% endfor %}
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.manage_jobs, name='manage-jobs'),
]
```

Comment: I changed the user model to inherit from AbstractUser rather than AbstractBaseUser. I also changed the jobs variable to jobs = Job.objects.filter(user = request.user.account) as you suggested. This raises the error ''Account' object has no attribute 'account''

Comment: Can you share how you saved the job?

Answer (score 0):

put this view and try:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def manage_jobs(request):
    if request.user.is_employee:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = JobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        jobs = Job.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
        context = {"form":form, "jobs":jobs}
        return render(request, 'employer/manage-jobs.html', context)
```

Comment: When using jobs = Job.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id), nothing is rendered to the template.

Comment: You need to first save the object in your DB then only it will get rendered on your page. I have updated the code please use this.

Comment: I have updated the question, as I think I might have a solution but I'm not sure how to implement my idea. I'd be grateful for you to take a look at the updated question.

Comment: Extremely sorry for the late response mate, I was not at my place, I didn't get you, can you please tell me more about your problem?

Comment: I need to filter each Job object by the user that created the object, so I only get the jobs that have been posted by the current user, or request.user. I thought a line like jobs = Job.objects.filter(user=request.user) would work if I had a foreignkey to my custom user model but it didn't

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to override django's User method, you should tell settings so it can understand that when you call 'request.user' you want it to

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.Account'
```

I recommend reading this article which explains how to extend/override django's User model

https://medium.com/@gabrielfgularte/custom-user-model-no-django-d9bdf2838bd8

Answer (score -1):

When you use .filter() it returns a list, even if there is only 1 item in the list, so your options are to:

jobs = Job.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0]

or even better, use get()

jobs = Job.objects.get(user=request.user)

Comment: When using jobs = Job.objects.get(user=request.user) I get the error 'Job matching query does not exist.'. When using jobs = Job.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0] I get the error 'list index out of range'

Comment: This won't work, he is iterating over the list of objects and you are only trying to return a single object which will eventually break his code.

Comment: whoops!  didn't notice the iteration!